# 'FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, notif' getting triggered every time app brought to foreground from background

Tags: react-native, react-native-fcm

I am using https://github.com/evollu/react-native-fcm with my react-native app for Push Notifications. Issue is the call back function show below gets called every time android app is brought to foreground from background (Even when no notifications are pushed by server)

In app.js componentDidMount-

```
FCM.on(FCMEvent.Notification, notif => {
      console.log("FCMEvent.Notification: " + JSON.stringify(notif));
}
```